# Given a random variable X, prove f(x) is a probability function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X be a random variable with $f_X(x) = P(X = x) = \frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{x}}{x!}$ for $x \geq 0$

Prove that $f_X(x)$ is a probability mass function.
Prove that $P(X$ is even $) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + e^{-2\mu})$

Work done so far:

First of all I assume there was a typo in the question since the definition of a probability function includes the following condition: $P(X = x) = f_X(x) = f_X$

I believe I proved that by trivially using the definition of $X$ that was given.

However, it must also fulfill the condition that: $\forall x \in R, f_X(x) \geq 0$ and that $f_X$ sums to 1.

I don't know how to prove that first of these part, since I don't know what $\mu$ is equal to. I read that $\mu$ is the expected value of $X$, but I also don't know how to calculate that without using the function that $\mu$ is part of. Could anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Congratulations on posting the $\color{blue}{Half}$ $\color{blue}{Millionth}$ $\color{blue}{Question}$  (Accurate up to any deletions)

Comment: 1. You need to show that $f(x)$ sums to 1. 2.You need to sum $f(x)$ for even $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution you are citing is called [*Poisson distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with parameter $\mu$ and write $X\sim$ **Poiss($\mu$)**. Now we want to show, that $f_X(x) = \mathbf{P}(X = x) = \frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{x}}{x!}$ is really a **pmf** with mass on the **non-negative integers**. We don't need to know what $\mu$ actually describes - as long as $\mu>0$ holds as **pointed out in the comment** - we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{P}(X = x)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{x}}{x!}=e^{-\mu}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^{x}}{x!}=e^{-\mu}e^{\mu}\equiv 1
\end{align}
holds for all real $\mu$ but we have $\mathbf{P}(X = x)\geq 0$ only for $\mu>0$. 
As a matter of fact, $\mu$ inded describes the expectation of a Poisson distributed random variable.

Now let's try to figure out, what the probability of a Poisson distributed random variable $X$ is only taking even realizations. So we want to know
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}(X \text{ "is even"})=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{P}(X = 2x)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{2x}}{(2x)!} \tag 1
\end{align}
Now there several possibilities to determine the value of $(1)$. For example we know that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}(X \text{ "is even"})+\mathbf{P}(X \text{ "is odd"})=1 \\
\iff \\
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{2x}}{(2x)!}+\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{2x+1}}{(2x+1)!}=1
\end{align}
and further we can see that (needs to be justified) $\frac{d}{d\mu}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^{2x+1}}{(2x+1)!}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^{2x}}{(2x)!}$ which eventually leads to a linear ODE which could we now solve.

However, the easiest way is to check some [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) and then we can see that indeed we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^{2x}}{(2x)!}=\cosh(\mu)=\frac{e^{\mu}+e^{-\mu}}{2} \tag 2
\end{align}
and therefore by using $(2)$
\begin{align}
e^{-\mu}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^{2x}}{(2x)!}=e^{-\mu}\cosh(\mu)=e^{-\mu}\frac{e^{\mu}+e^{-\mu}}{2}=\frac12(1+e^{-2\mu}) \tag 3
\end{align}
Altogether we have because of $(3)$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}(X \text{ "is even"})=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{P}(X = 2x)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{2x}}{(2x)!}=\frac12(1+e^{-2\mu})
\end{align}
which is exactly what we wanted to show.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's very clear now.

Comment: While $\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^k}{k!}$ does indeed equal $1$ even when $\mu < 0$, the summands cannot be described as _probabilities_ in this case, can they? After all, the first axiom of probability theory is that probabilities are _nonnegative_ numbers.

Comment: @DilipSarwate you've got a point, a very valid one! I somehow overlooked this fact...by your next visit, it's gonna be fixed. thanks!

Comment: Good. Now consider that $$e^{-\mu} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\mu)^k}{k!} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\mu^{2m}}{(2m)!}-\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\mu^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}$$ and so $\displaystyle P\{X~\text{even}\} - P\{X~\text{odd}\} = e^{-2\mu}\implies P\{X~\text{even}\} = \frac{1+e^{-2\mu}}{2}$ ,without too much fuss about consulting tables and solving differential equations etc.

Comment: @DilipSarwate yeah...I was considering a somewhat similar approach, which is to simply write out the Taylor expansion of $e^{-\mu}$ and $e^{\mu}$ which leads to the same expression $$\frac 12 (e^{\mu}+e^{-\mu})=\frac 12(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\mu)^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\mu)^k}{k!})= \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\mu^{2m}}{(2m)!}$$ but I wasn't sure whether this is really a solid argument, it seems to me a bit hand-waving since we would have to argue using the partial cancellation of infinite sums. That's why I chose the safe way

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but it got too long to be a comment.

$\mu$ is a *positive* number. Also, I don't know what your book means by a "probability function" because that phrase is not used in English. Are you translating from another language? In English, the probability *mass* function of a *discrete* random variable is denoted by $p_X(\cdot)$ (sometimes as $f_X(\cdot))$ and $p_X(a)$ is the probability that $X = a$. $p_X(a)$ has positive value only for *some* values of $a$, not the $x \geq 0$ meaning *all* nonnegative real numbers that you seemingly assert in your first sentence. Also, your definition of probability function should include a statement such as $\sum_a p_X(a) = 1$ (where
the sum is restricted to those $a$ for which $p_X(a) > 0$) in addition to $p_X(a) \geq 0$. If you did not check the former condition,
how can you assert that what you have is a "probability function"?

Comment: thanks for correcting me, I was translating from spanish. I forgot to add that the function had to add up to 1 but I've added that and clarified that it's a probability mass function. the $x \geq 0$ is taken verbatim from the original question.

Comment: Does it say anywhere that $x\geq 0$ must be an _integer_?

Comment: It doesn't explicitly say it, but maybe that's what they meant since they ask for the probability of X being even.

Comment: @user2566976 usually you call a *probability mass function "pmf"* a distribution function, which is based on a discrete probability distribution. In the continuous case you call the analogous a *probability density function*. Further  $P(X = x)$ would be zero if you deal with a continuous distribution function.